# Find the stationary distribution of the following Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose Markov chain $\{X_{n},n\geq 1\}$ with space $I=\{0,1,2,...\}$ and 
$$p_{i j}=e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{i \wedge j} C_{i}^{k}(1-q)^{k} q^{i-k} \frac{\lambda^{j-k}}{(j-k) !}$$
where $i\wedge j=min\{i,j\}$ and $\lambda>0,0<q<1$ are constants.
Please show that
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} p_{i j}^{(n)}=\frac{1}{j !} e^{-\frac{\lambda}{q}}\left(\frac{\lambda}{q}\right)^{j}$$

Comment: I think you could substitute this result for $\pi_j$ back into $\pi P = \pi$ and verify that this holds

Comment: Yeah, it works. But it is the last way I would like to use to solve the problem. Hope there is a way more elegant instead of verification a posteriori. Anyway, thanks a lot~~ @GeorgeDewhirst

Comment: What is $C_i^k$? $\binom ki$?

Comment: $C_{i}^{k}=\frac{i!}{k!(i-k)!}$@Math1000